# Why is it coming up with "IndexError: string index out of range"?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the no of times each character comes in the
sentence.

```
message = 'It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.'
c = 0
for  i in message:
   a=0
   for a in range(len(message) + 1):
    if i == message[a]:
     c+=1
   print(str(i)+ ' comes ' + str(c) + ' times.')
   c=0
```

Comment: Because the string index is out of range: why `len(message) + 1`?

Comment: How can `range(len(message) + 1)` _not_ throw an index error? You took the length of the list of possible indices and then threw an extra one in that can't exist

Comment: Valid string indexes go from `0` to `len(message) - 1`, which is why range() conveniently also only goes from `0` to `end - 1`. So remove the `+ 1` in your range() statement and this will resolve your IndexError. (There are other issues with your algorithm too, but this will take care of your immediate question.)

Comment: Initialize `c` before use, not afterwards. Or simply `c = message.count(i)`.

Comment: @Daniel they did initialize `c` before use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for a in range(len(message) + 1):
```

If you have a message with five characters, the valid indexes are `[0]` through `[4]`, but this loop will keep going to `[5]`, which is out of range.

Take out the `+ 1` from your range.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python have a starting index of 0, so when you iterate an index over the length of the string plus one with `range(len(message) + 1)`, you would end up exceeding the the last index of the string when the index becomes `len(message)`. Change it to `range(len(message))` instead and the code would work.